# Add Check Boxes in Facebook Messenger Chat Room

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I want to add check boxes in chat room of facebook messenger. I have been searching but could not find any helpful material! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can get check boxes via [Chat Extensions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/guides/chat-extensions).